# "go run" is going in infinite loop using sublime text 3

Tags: go, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, gosublime

I am trying to run go code in sublime text 3.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

However, when I go under `Tools -> Build` I see that the program goes in infinite loop.

```
GoSublime r17.03.05-1 9o: type `help` for help and command documentation

[ `go run main.go` ⌛ ]
[ ~/Documents/SublimeWorkspace/ ] #
```

Please let me know what I might be missing here.

Comment: Where do you see this infinite loop?

Comment: try to run your program from a terminal

Answer (score 0):

Open sublime
Goto Tools->Build System-> New build System. Paste below lines in the file and save by some_name.sublime-build

```
{
"shell_cmd": "go run $file",
"shell":true
}
```

Goto Tools->Build system->`<select-your-build or automatic>`

Goto Tools->Build

Done cheers :)